# Animated TV show about Meccano-like robots fighting other robots

Tags: story-identification, robots, animated-series

OK, so when I was little between 2010-2016, my brother and I watched an English show with animated robots that looked like Lego, but chunkier and not exactly Lego, almost like Meccano or something, fighting bad robots. The colours of the robots I can remember are green, red, white, and maybe blue, and I really feel like watching it, but I threw the DVD out. Does anyone know what this is??? I’m sorry but that’s really all I can remember, but there was a part where they were in a portal or a multicolour tornado, and the enemy was a big white machine or something.

Comment: Just to clarify, was this an animated series/cartoon? And if so, could it have been Japanese in origin, i.e. anime? Or was it more likely a western production?

Comment: There are hundreds of robots/mecha shows. This is too light on details and has too many possible answers to be a fit for this site. Please [edit] in more specific details, otherwise this should be closed as too broad.

Comment: @Jenayah - There's a few new (unique) details edited in. Sufficient to allow an ID

Comment: @AVERY - You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Bionicles, perhaps? They certainly look like Lego crossed with Meccano.